# Restore database from backup in asp mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database-restore

i am new in asp mvc and i am trying to make actions that backup database and restore it from the backup file

here the code

```
public class BackupController : Controller
{
    private RemasEntities1 db = new RemasEntities1();
    // GET: Backup
    public ActionResult BackupDatabase()
    {
        string dbPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/DBBackup.bak");
        using (var db = new RemasEntities1())
        {
            var cmd = String.Format("BACKUP DATABASE {0} TO DISK='{1}' WITH FORMAT, MEDIANAME='DbBackups', MEDIADESCRIPTION='Media set for {0} database';"
                , "Remas", dbPath);
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, cmd);
        }
        return new FilePathResult(dbPath, "application/octet-stream");
    }

   
    public ActionResult RestoreDatabase()
    {
        string dbPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/DBBackup.bak");
        using (var db = new RemasEntities1())
        {

            var cmd = String.Format("restore DATABASE {0} from DISK='{1}';"
                , "Remas", dbPath);
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, cmd);
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

the backup action works good, but when i try to restore database from restore action, it throw an exception

> An exception of type sql.data.sqlexception' occured in entityframework.sqlserver.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Restore cannot process database 'Remas' because it is in use by this session. It is recommended that the master database be used when performing this operation

Comment: It sounds like your connecting to `Remas` database to restore that database rather than `Master`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `master`:

```
var cmd = String.Format("USE master restore DATABASE Remas from DISK='{0}' WITH REPLACE;", dbPath);
```

Comment: it show error    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232060
  Message=The tail of the log for the database "Remas" has not been backed up. Use BACKUP LOG WITH NORECOVERY to backup the log if it contains work you do not want to lose. Use the WITH REPLACE or WITH STOPAT clause of the RESTORE statement to just overwrite the contents of the log.

Comment: @Sarah_Ayyad See edit - you need to use `WITH REPLACE`